# Insertar 100 veces un registro en mysql en varios servidores

Tags: mysql, python

Hola quisiera saber si hay manera de ejecutar un script que inserte el mismo registro 100 veces y esta se replique en varios servidores mysql.

Hice este script en python

```
import pymysql

try:
    conexion = pymysql.connect(host='172.16.2.9',
                             user='anonimo',
                             password='hola',
                             db='calificaciones')
    try:
        with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
            for consulta in range(1,10001):
                consulta = "INSERT INTO pbd2019 VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
                cursor.execute(consulta, ("216411051","Frank Miller", 100))
            conexion.commit()
    finally:
        conexion.close()
except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
    print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
```

Y si funciona para solamente un host y tengo la duda de que si se puede ejecutar el mismo script a varios servidores de mysql usando el mismo usuario.

Por ejemplo que todos los servidores de mysql en la red 172.16.2.x se pueda ejecutar al mismo tiempo el script

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Aquí un script el cual imprime todas las direcciones ip del segmento de red ***172.16.2.0***

```
import ipaddress


red_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('172.16.2.0/24')
d = ipaddress.ip_address('172.16.2.0')
for d in red_ipv4:
    print(d)
print()
```

Ya una vez teniendo las direcciones ip en teoria solo seria que en el atributo ***host*** de la conexión a mysql se sustituyera por los valores arrojados del script de las ip, ¿no?

Comment: No entiendo bien para que lo quieres hacer. Yo lo que aria es un array de objetos con los parámetros de las conexiones. Después dentro aria un for sobre el array de conexiones he insertaría los datos necesarios por cada iteración de ese for.

Comment: @FrankMiller, está resuelta tu pregunta? Si ya lo resolviste, por favor selecciona una respuesta, y si aun no lo resuelves, has un comentario para tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: Si me sirvió el ultimo script que pusiste, si funciona, trate de añadir el map asincrono como me lo sugeriste pero no pude implementarlo al código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solución a lo que expones consiste en crear algun iterador de hostnames, y hacer las operaciones sobre este conjunto. En este caso, corresponden a direcciones ip, por lo que la solución podría ser algo así.

```
import pymysql
import ipaddress
red_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('172.16.2.0/24')

for ip in red_ipv4:
    try:
        conexion = pymysql.connect(host=str(ip),
                             user='anonimo',
                             password='hola',
                             db='calificaciones')
       try:
            with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
                for consulta in range(1,10001):
                    consulta = "INSERT INTO pbd2019 VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
                    cursor.execute(consulta, ("216411051","Frank Miller", 100))
                conexion.commit()
        finally:
            conexion.close()
    except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
        print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
```

Ahora, como las operaciones ocurren en distintos host, podrias hacerlo de manera concurrente mediante un [map asincrono](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map), para que sea más rapido.

Answer (score 0):

El script me quedó de la siguiente manera

```
import pymysql
import ipaddress

def ip():
    red_ipv4 = ipaddress.ip_network('172.16.2.0/24')
    d = ipaddress.ip_address('172.16.2.0')
    for d in red_ipv4:
        print(d)

try:
    conexion = pymysql.connect(host=ip(),
                             user='anonimo',
                             password='hola',
                             db='calificaciones')
    try:
        with conexion.cursor() as cursor:
            for consulta in range(1,101):
                consulta = "INSERT INTO pbd2019 VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
                cursor.execute(consulta, ("216411051","Heisenberg", 100))
            conexion.commit()
    finally:
        conexion.close()
except (pymysql.err.OperationalError, pymysql.err.InternalError) as e:
    print("Ocurrió un error al conectar: ", e)
```

Comment: Esto no funciona porque la funcion ip no retorna nada, asi que tiraría error de que host es None.